# For which natural numbers $a, b, c$ is the number $\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2-1}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}$ an integer?

Tags: number-theory

> For which natural numbers $a, b, c$ is the number $\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2-1}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}$ an integer?

Please give me some tips on how to move it what can be applied what methods to use.

I used symmetric polynomials. I multiplied the bottom to the end and then substituted:

$$x=a+b+c \\
y=ab+ac+bc \\
z=abc$$

and top:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+ac+bc)$$

I got such an expression- $$\frac{x^2-2y}{x+y+z}$$

But what do I do next?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: You can help me?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? It looks like a contest problem…

Comment: From a certain foreign forum.

Comment: Personally, no, but others here most likely could.

Comment: My advice would be to start with the case $c=0$. I don’t think it’s trivial, and it’s almost certainly necessary.

Comment: MathSE reviewers need to verify that the contest is no longer active.  What is the exact source of the problem?

Comment: I do not know what is the source of this problem was posted on a Polish forum by some user who creates task sets for forum users there.

Comment: $\dfrac{-1 + x^2 - 2 y}{1 + x + y + z}$, but how find $a,b,c$ from $x,y,z$?

Comment: Well, exactly how?

Comment: Which Polish forum?  What is the exact webpage that has the problem?

Comment: [link](https://matematyka.pl/teoria-liczb-f26/dla-jakich-liczb-naturalnych-liczba-jest-calkowita-t455371.html)

Comment: $\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2-1}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)} = k \implies a^2 + b^2 = (1 + c) (1 - c + (1 + a) (1 + b) k)$.

Find $c,k$ from divisors of $a^2 + b^2$.

Solutions are infinite, expamples $(a,b,c,k)$=`(12,143,20592,11), (14,195,38220,13), (18,323,104652,17), (20,399,159600,19)`.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov  there is also a tree structure for each fixed ratio $k,$   analogous to the tree for  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Comment: Fty, I do not know how to reach an answer using your symmetric polynomial idea. The  Vieta Jumping idea has been a part of mathematics contests since about 1988.  It is not really difficult, but you do need to study it and do easier problems before applying it to your current problem. Next: I do not really know what you mean by and "answer."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fits well into Vieta Jumping. It also resembles the  Markov-Hurwitz equations.

I took $x=1+a, y=1+b, z=1+c$   Then we have
$$   (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 +(z-1)^2 = 1 + wxyz  $$
for integer $w$  I also decided to take $w,x,y,z >0$

For any quadruple $(w;x,y,z)$  we may jump one of $x,y,z$   to get a quadruple with the same $w.$  Call a replacement for $x$
$$   x' =  2 + wyz -x   $$
I admit that sometimes $x'$ comes out negative, so it is a little optimistic to keep just positive values. On the other hand, if we allow $0,$   we do get Hurwitz's notion of "fundamental solution" for the quadruple $(w,0,1,1).$  The hard part then comes in dealing with this conjecture: that every solution with all positive entries can be jumped down to that fixed root, $(w,0,1,1).$  I was surprised when I found that the [Markov-Hurwitz equation](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf) failed this when $n=14$  Hurwitz tabulated $n \leq 10.$

There is always a quadruple   for any $w,$   take $y=1, z=1$ but then $x= w + 2$ That is, $(w, 2+w,1,1).$  But then we may immediately begin jumping,  to get an infinite tree
with the same $w$.   Here are several quadruples with $w=1$  for example..

```
 w         x         y         z
 1         3         1         1
 1         4         3         1
 1        13         4         3
 1        37        13         3
 1        51        13         4
 1       100        37         3
 1       193        51         4
 1       265       100         3
 1       480        37        13
 1       661        51        13
 1       697       265         3
 1       723       193         4
```

I don't believe I know how to illustrate this tree.  I had a scanner and could make drawings by hand, but the scanner died.

Try the above  quadruples, see if you can draw the tree. For a quadruple, one may jump $x$   as shown above, or one of
$$   y' =  2 + wzx -y   $$

$$   z' =  2 + wxy -z   $$

Here are quadruples with $1250 \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq 1$  and $1 \leq w  \leq  16$

```
 w         x         y         z
 1       100        37         3
 1        13         4         3
 1       193        51         4
 1       265       100         3
 1         3         1         1
 1        37        13         3
 1         4         3         1
 1       480        37        13
 1        51        13         4
 1       661        51        13
 1       697       265         3
 1       723       193         4

 2       100        81         1
 2      1024       961         1
 2      1089      1024         1
 2      1156      1089         1
 2       121       100         1
 2      1225      1156         1
 2       144       121         1
 2        16         9         1
 2       169       144         1
 2       196       169         1
 2       225       196         1
 2        25        16         1
 2       256       225         1
 2       289        16         9
 2       289       256         1
 2       324       289         1
 2       361       324         1
 2        36        25         1
 2       400       361         1
 2         4         1         1
 2       441       400         1
 2       484       441         1
 2        49        36         1
 2       529       484         1
 2       576       529         1
 2       577        73         4
 2       625       576         1
 2        64        49         1
 2       676       625         1
 2       729       676         1
 2        73         9         4
 2       784       729         1
 2       801        25        16
 2        81        64         1
 2       841       784         1
 2       900       841         1
 2         9         4         1
 2       961       900         1

 3       121        45         1
 3        16         5         1
 3       241        16         5
 3       320       121         1
 3        45        16         1
 3         5         1         1
 3       841       320         1

 4        25         6         1
 4       361        96         1
 4       601        25         6
 4         6         1         1
 4        96        25         1

 5       175        36         1
 5        36         7         1
 5         7         1         1
 5       841       175         1

 6       288        49         1
 6        49         8         1
 6         8         1         1

 7       441        64         1
 7        64         9         1
 7         9         1         1

 8        10         1         1
 8       640        81         1
 8        81        10         1

 9       100        11         1
 9        11         1         1
 9       891       100         1

10      1200       121         1
10        12         1         1
10       121        12         1

11        13         1         1
11       144        13         1

12        14         1         1
12       169        14         1

13        15         1         1
13       196        15         1

14        16         1         1
14       225        16         1

15        17         1         1
15       256        17         1

16        18         1         1
16       289        18         1
```

Pages about what I called Vieta Jumping, from a book by Engel.

[image]

Comment: Will or someone else can address my previous questions because I no longer know if I'm writing in the right place or if I'll be criticized further:)

Comment: @Fty56  I don't understand what you want. I gave a complete answer.  I cannot instruct you in Vieta Jumping, but there are many book that include it, I am sure there are many books in Polish that tell you everything you might need. I also think you would have a better experience if you got a friend who is fluent in English  to  translate. Next: how old are you?  What is your background in mathematics?

Comment: My question is what did you use to keep those answers? Only Vieta Jumping?

Comment: @Fty56  yes...........

Comment: And you can show at least one example of how it works?